# How to add text and blank line at the beginning of every file in a given directory?

Tags: source-code, editing

How do I add a new line at the beginning of every file in /home/johnny containing the text "Hello", followed by a blank line? Also, I have to delete every useless space or tab at the ending of every line(if a line contains only spaces or tabs, they will be deleted, but the line must be kept).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (started in `/home/johnny/`):

`for f in * ; do  awk 'BEGIN {print "Hello\n";} {gsub("([ \t]+)$", ""); print $0; }' "$f" >"$f.2"; done`

It creates `.2` files in the same directory. These files contain the modifications.

The `for` statement lists all files in the directory. If you'd like to process only text files, you could use `*.txt` instead of `*`.

The `awk` performs 2 tasks:

1. Prepends each file with "Hello" and the blank line.
2. Removes spaces and tab characters from the end of each line.

The results are displayed on the standard output.

Finally a simple redirection creates the `.2` files from the processed standard output.

It works on files with spaces in their names, because `$f` is quoted.

If you do not want to keep the original files, modify the command as follows:

`for f in * ; do  awk 'BEGIN {print "Hello\n";} {gsub("([ \t]+)$", ""); print $0; }' "$f" >"$f.2"; mv "$f.2" "$f"; done`

The main addition is a *move* command that replaces the original files with the modified version.

Comment: do I have to make a script containing those instructions or the instructions can be put directly in the terminal? And if I do not want to keep the original files What do I do?

Comment: You can put the command into a single line. (This is how I tested it.) I've updated the answer with the option to replace original files.